# Service invoked too many times in a short time

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error message to the following script.  "Service invoked too many times in a short time: exec qps. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls."

I've given my code below. Can you help me to stop this error message? Note: I'm using an array formula imported from another sheet. The trigger is set to work on Change.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Direct');
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var values = range.getValues();
    var rows_deleted = 0; 

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {

            var value = values[i][j];

            //row numbers are 1-based, not zero-based like this for-loop, so we add one AND...
            //every time we delete a row, all of the rows move down one, so we will subtract this count
            var row = i + 1 - rows_deleted;

            //if the type is a number, we don't need to look
            if (typeof value === 'string') {

                var result = value.search("Remove");

                //the .search() method returns the index of the substring, or -1 if it is not found
                //we only care if it is found, so test for not -1

                if (result !== -1) {
                    sheet.deleteRow(row);
                    rows_deleted++;
                }
            }  
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: which line of that script is causing the error?

Comment: @JaromandaX I get this error message via email "Service invoked too many times in a short time: exec qps. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls." That's all I know.The trigger i use is OnChange which occurs from Arrayformula import range. Note: I'm not a developer.

Comment: well, none of the code you've shown seems to call any "service", so the code you've shown is possibly irrelevant

Comment: @JaromandaX Here is a screenshot of the error message I keep getting https://photos.app.goo.gl/01YGCvJUxLTx9l0o1

Comment: nothing in that scrceenshot is new information ... where in your code are you calling any service?

Comment: @JaromandaX I really can't understand what you are referring to :(

Comment: I really can't understand what part of the code you posted you think is causing the error, and why you think that code is the culprit

Comment: Because When I click on the "Click here" (in the screenshot) it takes me to the trigger belong to the code I've pasted above.

Comment: The code is executed remotely by a service called `exec`. That's just how Google Sheets works.